# Edit Books Records PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I am currently in the middle of constructing a website for my own personal education to better myselft at work and have encountered a problem.

I am wanting to have the ability to update records located on my database via a form.

This is what I have got so far, am i on the right lines?

Thanks in advance

Edit Book Form

```
<?php 

include 'database_conn.php';   // make db connection

//Get the bookISBN from the request stream
 $bookISBN = $_REQUEST['bookISBN'];

//use that code in an sql statement to retrieve the details for the Book 
$sql = "SELECT bookISBN bookTitle bookYear bookPrice FROM nbc_book where     bookISBN = $bookISBN" ;

//Execute the query 
$rsAdmin = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 

//get the records from the result set into variables
$adminBook = mysqli_fetch_array($rsAdmin);
$bookISBN = $adminBook['bookISBN'];
$bookTitle= $adminBook['bookTitle'];
$bookYear= $adminBook['bookYear'];
$bookPrice= $adminBook['bookPrice'];
//Display those variables in a form 
?>

<form action ='editBook.php' method = 'GET'>
<?php

echo "StudentID: $bookISBN<br />";
echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'bookISBN' value ='$bookISBN' />";
echo "<input type ='text' name'$bookTitle' value='$bookTitle'>";
echo "Book Title:<input type ='text' name'bookTitle'     value='$bookTitle'><br />";
echo "Book Year:<input type ='text' name'bookYear'     value='$bookYear'><br />";
echo "Book Price:<input type ='text' name'bookPrice' value='$bookPrice'><br />";
echo "<input type ='submit' value='Save'/>";


 mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
</form>
```

Edit Book Process

```
<?php

// make db connection
include 'database_conn.php';

//Get the bookISBN from the request stream
$bookISBN = $_REQUEST['bookISBN'];
$bookTitle = $_REQUEST['bookTitle'];
$bookYear = $_REQUEST['bookYear'];
$bookPrice = $_REQUEST['bookPrice'];

//construct an SQL Statement
$sql = "UPDATE nbc_books set bookTitle ='$bookTitle', bookYear ='$bookYear,     $bookPrice where bookISBN = '$bookISBN'";

//execute the SQL statment
$rsBookUpdate = mysql_query ($bookUpdateSQL);

if ($rsBookUpdate === false)    {
echo 'Updating Book failed $bookISBN, $bookTitle failed: ' . mysql_error    ();
}

?>

<!--draw link taking them back to books list-->
<a href= "Books.php">Go back to all book records</a>
```

Comment: This is the record I am currently presented with:Notice: Undefined index: bookISBN in /home/unn_w13045128/public_html/test/editbookform1.php on line 14
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bookYear bookPrice FROM nbc_book where bookISBN =' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

you missed quote (`): please check with your database field and query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE nbc_books set bookTitle ='$bookTitle', bookYear ='$bookYear',   bookPrice = '$bookPrice' where bookISBN = '$bookISBN'";
```

Comment: @DanielWilldigg..have you tried or still face the issue?

Comment: Sorry Hardy I did not notice you had replied and yes still face same issue :/

Comment: @DanielWilldigg same error you found? then please check with your database table filed as well. you can try with `$sql = "UPDATE nbc_books set bookTitle ='$bookTitle', bookYear ='$bookYear',   bookPrice = '$bookPrice' where bookISBN = ".$bookISBN;`

Comment: yeah same error, but it says it is on my editBookForm.php and not edit book process